# How to pipe multiple ReadableStreams to a single WriteStream?

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I'm dealing with a firewall limit where I can only POST 10MB at a time. In order to handle larger uploads, I'd like to use something like http://www.resumablejs.com, write multiple chunks to disk, and recombine them at the end.

I'm just writing tests now, but something in my implementation is wrong.

First, I split the file like this:

```
    const splitFile = async () => {
      const chunkSize = 1024 * 1024;
      const photo = fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(FIXTURES, 'hello-tron.jpg'));

      // Write to 2 files
      photo.on('readable', function() {
        const file1 = path.resolve(TEMP, 'chunk.jpg.1');
        const file2 = path.resolve(TEMP, 'chunk.jpg.2');
        let data;
        while (data = this.read(chunkSize)) {
          if (!fs.existsSync(file1)) {
            const output1 = fs.createWriteStream(file1);
            output1.write(data);
            output1.close();
            return;
          }
          const output2 = fs.createWriteStream(file2);
          output2.write(data);
          if (data === null) {
            output2.close();
          }
        }
      });

      return new Promise(resolve => {
        photo.on('end', resolve);
      });
    };
```

Then I reassemble it like this:

```
const recombine = async () => {
  const output = fs.createWriteStream(path.resolve(TEMP, 'recombined.jpg'));
  const file1 = path.resolve(TEMP, 'chunk.jpg.1');
  const file2 = path.resolve(TEMP, 'chunk.jpg.2');
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const stream1 = fs.createReadStream(file1);
    const stream2 = fs.createReadStream(file2);

    const recombinator = new Recombinator({
      readables: [stream1, stream2]
    });

    stream1.on('readable', () => {
      stream2.on('readable', () => {
        recombinator.pipe(output);
      });
    });

    stream1.on('end', () => {
      stream2.on('end', () => {
        resolve();
      });
    });
  })
};
```

This is the `Recombinator` class:

```
/* Takes multiple readable streams and returns a single
 * readable stream that can be piped to a writable stream
 */
const {Readable} = require('stream');

class Recombinator extends Readable {
  constructor(opts) {
    super({...opts, readables: undefined});
    const self = this;
    self.readables = opts.readables || [];
  }

  _read(size) {
    this.push(this._getChunk(size));
  }

  _getChunk(size) {
    const reader = this.readables.find(r => !r.closed);
    if (!reader) {
      return null;
    }
    const data = reader.read(size);
    if (!data) {
      reader.closed = true;
      return this._getChunk(size);
    }
    return data;
  }
}

module.exports = Recombinator;
```

Here's the original image:

[image: Original]

Here's the reassembled image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem was in thinking that the `readable` event is only fired once but it's fired each time there's data to be read. Nesting the event handlers probably wasn't great either.

The solution I'm using is to change the `Recombinator` constructor like so:

```
constructor(opts) {
    super({...opts, readables: undefined});
    const self = this;
    self.readables = opts.readables || [];

    self._readableCount = 0;
    self._endedCount = 0;

    // Attach listeners to know when all readables are open and closed
    self.readables.forEach(r => {
      r.on('readable', () => {
        if (r._markedReadable) {
          return;
        }
        r._markedReadable = true;
        self._readableCount++;
      });
      r.on('end', () => {
        if (r._markedEnded) {
          return;
        }
        r._markedEnded = true;
        self._endedCount++;
      });
    })
  }
```

and adding async methods in order to wait until all readers are open like so:

```
  async ready(retry = 10) {
    if (this._readableCount === this.readables.length) {
      return Promise.resolve();
    }
    if (retry === 0) {
      return Promise.reject(`Timeout waiting for ${this.readables.length} readables to open - got ${this._readableCount}`);
    }
    await delay(500);
    return this.ready(retry - 1);
  }

  async done(retry = 10) {
    if (this._endedCount === this.readables.length) {
      return Promise.resolve();
    }
    if (retry === 0) {
      return Promise.reject(`Timeout waiting for ${this.readables.length} readables to end - got ${this._endedCount}`);
    }
    await delay(500);
    return this.done(retry - 1);
  }
```